# Why do I get "\common Files" at the end of string inside my struct

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct

I am using char arr[] insidea struct

I used temporary array to get string from user and it works fine ,

when I try to copy this temporary array to the variable array inside the struct I get \command files at end of string

```
for (u32 i=0;i<name_size;i++)
{
    printf("\nin While");
    pn->name[i]=temp_name[i];
    
}
```

Comment: my guess (in the absense of any code) is that you do not have a \0 terminator

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: yup - you are not copying a null, use strcpy instead of copying byte by byte, assuming name_size is the result of strlen of temp_name

Comment: Have you allocated the memory for the `name[]` at the end of the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you must do it byte by byte then do this

```
u32 i;
for (i=0;i<name_size;i++)
{
   printf("\nin While");
   pn->name[i]=temp_name[i];

}
 pn->name[i] = '\0';
```

ie - add the trailing zero. simpler would be strcpy